# How to handle UTF-8 email headers (like Subject:) using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, unicode, utf-8

I'm an email n00b but I am working on an application that sends HTML email with Unicode characters (as my friend noted "enjoy encoding hell").

The `Subject:` header comes from user input and therefore may contain Unicode characters. Some mail clients (like GMail and Outlook 2007) are OK with this, but from my reading it seems the right way to do this is to use [MIME Encoded-Word encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) for the headers.

I cannot find a Ruby library to do this. Is there one?

Also, is there a header to add that will tell mail clients to use UTF-8 when displaying the message? We are sending multipart email so our `Content-Type` is `multipart/mixed`. Apple Mail.app in particular is not using the right encoding, even though it's specified in the individual parts as being UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahah! `ActionMailer::Quoting` has a `quoted_printable` method.

So here's what I did:

```
def my_email(foo)
  ...
  @subject = quoted_printable(foo.some_subject_with_accented_chars, 'utf-8')
  ...
end
```

Doing this convinced Mail.app to display the rest of the email using UTF-8. Now to test the rest!

Comment: This method does not exist in rails 4 :( - any alternative?

Answer (score 10):

Your can optionally do the same using Base64 encoding:

```
require "base64"

value  = Base64.encode64("Your UTF-8 string")
header = "=?UTF-8?B?" + value + "?="
```

Note the "B", that marks Base64 encoded payload, as opposed to the "Q" which marks "Q-encoded" payload. The latter could be faked by URL-encoding the string and replacing all "%" characters with "=".

By "faking" I mean this: It would produce a valid result, but maybe more characters are encoded than would be necessary. The spec allows for encoding every character there is with `"=" + ByteCodeAsHex`, it merely impairs human readability of the raw headers. UrlEncode is + `.gsub(/%/, "=")` not a bad compromise when nothing else is available.

Comment: Thanks! I started out by using Base64 but I was worried about spam filters flagging that, so I switched to quoted printable. I found a method to do that in ActionMailer::Quoting. Looks like it works too!

Comment: I don't think spam filters would flag this, this is a valid header value.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any proof of that. I thought spammers might try it to get around naive content filters.

Comment: Q encoded has to be packed. like str.to_a.pack("M") or something. See this for decoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473952/is-there-a-way-to-decode-q-encoded-strings-in-ruby/8363256#8363256

Answer (score 3):

Since none of the answers tells about whole message with pure Ruby, here it is.

```
Net::SMTP.start("localhost") do |smtp|
    smtp.open_message_stream opts[:sender_address], opts[:receiver_address] do |f|

        f.puts "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
        f.puts from
        f.puts to
        f.puts subject
        f.puts message
    end
end
```

Here you open connection to localhost. Using external SMTP server is also possible, refer to documentation of net/smtp.

First line sets character set used in the message. Rest of the lines are variables defined separately:

from is an address in form of `From: Name here <address@here.fi>`. If no name is wanted, only address can be specified, like `From: address@here.fi`.

to uses same syntax, with exception `From:` changed to `To:`.

subject is in form of Subject: subject here. For UTF-8, it needs to be Base64-encoded to be shown correctly for clients.

```
subject = "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?" + Base64.strict_encode64(subject) + "?="
```

Message is plain text message encoded in UTF-8, without any prefix. net/smtp will take care of forming proper mail.