# Is there a way to decode q-encoded strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, email, decoding

I'm working with mails, and names and subjects sometimes come q-encoded, like this:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?J=2E_Pablo_Fern=C3=A1ndez?=
```

Is there a way to decode them in Ruby? It seems TMail should take care of it, but it's not doing it.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form

Comment: @equivalent8 This isn't related to URI encoding. It's related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this to parse email subjects:

You could try the following:

```
str = "=?UTF-8?Q?J=2E_Pablo_Fern=C3=A1ndez?="
if m = /=\?([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\?(B|Q)\?([!->@-~]+)\?=/i.match(str)
        case m[2]
        when "B" # Base64 encoded
          decoded = Base64.decode64(m[3])
        when "Q" # Q encoded
          decoded = m[3].unpack("M").first.gsub('_',' ')
        else
          p "Could not find keyword!!!"
        end
        Iconv.conv('utf-8',m[1],decoded) # to convert to utf-8
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby includes a method of decoding Quoted-Printable strings:

```
puts "Pablo_Fern=C3=A1ndez".unpack "M"
# => Pablo_Fernández
```

But this doesn't seem to work on your entire string (including the `=?UTF-8?Q?` part at the beginning. Maybe you can work it out from there, though.

Comment: I got things like `< br>` and `< div>` with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old question but TMail::Unquoter (or its new incarnation Mail::Encodings) does the job as well.

```
TMail::Unquoter.unquote_and_convert_to(str, 'utf-8' )
```

or

```
Mail::Encodings.unquote_and_convert_to( str, 'utf-8' )
```

Comment: I got things like `<= br>` and `<= div>` with this

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient and up to date solution it seems to use the `value_decode` method of the [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail).

```
> Mail::Encodings.value_decode("=?UTF-8?Q?Greg_of_Google?=")
=> "Greg of Google"
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Encodings#value_decode-class_method

Answer (score 0):

Decoding on a line-per-line basis:

```
line.unpack("M")
```

Convert STDIN or file provided input of encoded strings into a decoded output:

```
if ARGV[0]
  lines = File.read(ARGV[0]).lines
else
  lines = STDIN.each_line.to_a
end

puts lines.map { |c| c.unpack("M") }.join
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help anyone wanting to test an email. delivery.html_part is normally encoded, but can be decoded to a straight HTML body using `.decoded`.

```
test "email test" do
  UserMailer.confirm_email(user).deliver_now
  assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
  delivery = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  assert_equal "Please confirm your email", delivery.subject
  assert delivery.html_part.decoded =~ /Click the link below to confirm your email/ # DECODING HERE
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is Ruby code you can cut-and-paste, if inclined. It will run tests if executed directly with ruby, `ruby ./copy-pasted.rb`. As done in the code, I use this module as a refinement to the String core class.

A few remarks on the solution:

1. Other solutions perform `.gsub('_', ' ')` on the unpacked string.  However, I do not believe this is correct, and can result in an incorrect decoding depending on the charsets.  [RFC2047 Section 4.2 (2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-4.2) indicates "`_` always represents hexidecimal `20`", so it seems correct to first substitute `=20` for `_` then rely on the unpack result. (This also makes the implementation more elegant.)  This is also discussed in [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520781/difference-with-q-encoding-and-quoted-printable).
2. To be more instructive, I have written the regular expression in free-spacing mode to allow comments (I find this generally helpful for complex regular expressions). If you adjust the regular expression, take note that free-spacing mode changes the matching of white-space, which must then be done escaped or as a character class (as in the code).  I've also [added the regular expression on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Tix4z6/1), so you can read an explanation of the named capture groups, lazy quantifiers, etc. and experiment yourself.
3. The regular expression will absorb space ( ; but not `TAB` or newline) between multiple Q-encoded phrases in a single string, as shown with string `test_4`.  This is because [RFC2047 Section 5 (1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-5) indicates that multiple Q encoded phrases must be separated from each other by linear white-space.  Depending on your use-case, absorbing the white-space may not be desired.
4. The regular expression `code` named capture permits unexpected quoted printable codes (other than `[bBqQ]` so that a match will occur and the code can raise an error.  This helps me to detect unexpected values when processing text.  Change the regular expression named capture for `code` to `[bBqQ]` if you do not want this behaviour. (There will be no match and the original string will be returned.)
5. It makes use of the global `Regexp.last_match` as a convenience in the `gsub` block.  You may need to take care if using this in multi-threaded code, I have not given this any consideration.

Additional references and reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

```rb
require "minitest/autorun"

module QuotedPrintableDecode
  class UnhandledCodeError < StandardError
    def initialize(code)
      super("Unhandled quoted printable code: '#{code}'.")
    end
  end

  @@qp_text_regex = %r{
    =\?                # Opening literal: `=?`
    (?<charset>[^\?]+) # Character set, e.g. "Windows-1252" in `=?Windows-1252?`
    \?                 # Literal: `?`
    (?<code>[a-zA-Z])  # Encoding, e.g. "Q" in `?Q?` (`B`ase64); [BbQq] expected, others raise
    \?                 # Literal: `?`
    (?<text>[^\?]+?)   # Encoded text, lazy (non-greedy) matched, e.g. "Foo_bar" in `?Foo_bar?`
    \?=                # Closing literal: `?=`
    (?:[ ]+(?==\?))?   # Optional separating linear whitespace if another Q-encode follows
  }x                   # Free-spacing mode to allow above comments, also changes whitespace match

  refine String do
    def decode_q_p(to: "UTF-8")
      self.gsub(@@qp_text_regex) do
        code, from, text = Regexp.last_match.values_at(:code, :charset, :text)
        q_p_charset_to_charset(code, text, from, to)
      end
    end

    private

    def q_p_charset_to_charset(code, text, from, to)
      case code
        when "q", "Q"
          text.gsub("_", "=20").unpack("M")
        when "b", "B"
          text.unpack("m")
        else
          raise UnhandledCodeError.new(code)
      end.first.encode(to, from)
    end
  end
end

class TestQPDecode < Minitest::Test
  using QuotedPrintableDecode

  def test_decode_single_utf_8_phrase
    encoded = "=?UTF-8?Q?J=2E_Pablo_Fern=C3=A1ndez?="
    assert_equal encoded.decode_q_p, "J. Pablo Fernández"
  end

  def test_decoding_preserves_space_between_unencoded_phrase
    encoded = "=?utf-8?Q?Alfred_Sanford?= <me@example.com>"
    assert_equal encoded.decode_q_p, "Alfred Sanford <me@example.com>"
  end

  def test_decodinge_multiple_adjacent_phrases_absorbs_separating_whitespace
    encoded = "=?Windows-1252?Q?Foo_-_D?= =?Windows-1252?Q?ocument_World=9617=96520;_Recor?= =?Windows-1252?Q?d_People_to_C?= =?Windows-1252?Q?anada's_History?="
    assert_equal encoded.decode_q_p, "Foo - Document World–17–520; Record People to Canada's History"
  end

  def test_decoding_string_without_encoded_phrases_preserves_original
    encoded = "Contains no QP phrases"
    assert_equal encoded.decode_q_p, encoded
  end

  def test_unhandled_code_raises
    klass = QuotedPrintableDecode::UnhandledCodeError
    message = "Unhandled quoted printable code: 'Z'."
    encoded = "=?utf-8?Z?Unhandled code Z?="

    raised_error = assert_raises(klass) { encoded.decode_q_p }
    assert_equal message, raised_error.message
  end
end
```