# Difference with Q encoding and Quoted Printable?

Tags: ruby, encoding, mime

My apology if I am asking a beginners question.

May I ask what is the difference between [**RFC2047 4.2** The "Q" encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-4.2) and [**RFC 2045 6.7** Quoted-Printable Content-Transfer-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7)?

From RFC2047:

> The "Q" encoding is similar to the "Quoted-Printable" content-transfer-encoding defined in RFC 2045.

I am trying to implement decode logic using Ruby. I have read the answer below and am trying to understand why `first.gsub('_',' ')` is required for *Q encoding*.

[Is there a way to decode q-encoded strings in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473952/is-there-a-way-to-decode-q-encoded-strings-in-ruby/8363256)

Comment: _"why `first.gsub('_',' ')` is required"_ – because in "Q" encoding, `' '` (space) may be represented as `'_'` (underscore).

Comment: I see . *rfc 2047 4.2. The "Q" encoding (2)* . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading RFC2047 again, I have realized that the approach below does not decode underscore properly in cases where underscore is encoded as `=5F`.

```
decoded = m[3].unpack('M').first.gsub('_',' ')
```

Instead, as described in the last sentence of [RFC2047 4.2 (2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-4.2):

> Note that the "_" always represents hexadecimal 20, even if the SPACE character occupies a different code position in the character set in use.

I have substituted literal underscore back to `=20` first, then unpack it.

I have coded as below:

```
decoded = m[3].gsub('_', '=20').unpack('M').first()
```