# How to properly decode string with quoted-printable encoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, quoted-printable

I'm trying to decode what I think is some quoted-printable encoded text that appears in an MBox email archive. I will give one example of some text I am having trouble with.

In the MBox, the following text appears:

"Demarcation by Theresa Castel=E3o-Lawless"

Properly decoded, I think this should appear as:

"Demarcation by Theresa Castelão-Lawless"

I'm basing my statement of what it should properly look like both off of

1) a web archive of the email in which the text is properly rendered as "Demarcation by Theresa Castelão-Lawless"

and 2) this page, which shows "=E3" as corresponding to a "ã" for quoted-printable https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html

I've tried the code below but it gives the wrong output.

```
string = "Demarcation by Theresa Castel=E3o-Lawless"

decoded_string = Mail::Encodings::QuotedPrintable.decode(string)

puts decoded_string + "\n"
```

The result from the code above is 
"Demarcation by Theresa Castel?o-Lawless"
but as stated above, I want
"Demarcation by Theresa Castelão-Lawless"

Comment: Regarding 2) that page is all about ISO-8859-1 aka ISO Latin 1. In Ruby, strings are UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid weird Rails stuff when you have plain old good ruby to accomplish a task. [`String#unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) is your friend.

```
"Demarcation by Theresa Castel=E3o-Lawless".
  unpack("M").first. # unpack as quoted printable
  force_encoding(Encoding::ISO_8859_1).
  encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
#⇒ "Demarcation by Theresa Castelão-Lawless"
```

or, as suggested in comments by @Stefan, one can pass the source encoding as the 2nd argument:

```
"Demarcation by Theresa Castel=E3o-Lawless".
  unpack("M").first. # unpack as quoted printable
  encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')
```

*Note:* `force_encoding` is needed to tell the engine this is single-byte ISO with european accents before encoding into target `UTF-8`.

Comment: You can pass the source encoding as the 2nd argument: `encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')`

Comment: @Stefan yes, I decided that way it’s somewhat more explicit. Maybe I’m wrong, I’ll update the answer.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I'm unsure how to handle this on SO, but there is another very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473952/is-there-a-way-to-decode-q-encoded-strings-in-ruby/67418207#67418207  Strictly speaking, it is not a duplicate because this question has a string which only contains hexidecimal sequences, without the QP delimiters, charset and code.  `unpack` is still a great solution in that case as well, I wrote complete example code around it.  A reference to the other Q/A might be helpful to readers here.