# =0A in the title of an email sent with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, encoding

This is an action in my mailer

```
  def review_book(book)
    @book = book
    @subject = "We received #{@book.title}"
    mail(:to => @book.user[:email], :subject => @subject) do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

But the mails are being sent with this title

> We received =0AIb and Little Christina

@book.title is "Ib and Little Christina" (without the quotes)

I think is something with the encoding... but don't know how to fix it.

Please help? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341708/how-to-handle-utf-8-email-headers-like-subject-using-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called quoted printable encoding.  It would appear you have an ascii(10) character in the title.
[Quoted Printable Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)